# When I use the re.split function in Python, it keeps the separators. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to separate the speaker from the speech in a document that looks like this:

> Jim Friedland, Director Investor Relations: Thank you. Good afternoon, everyone, and
> welcome to Alphabet’s first-quarter 2021 earnings conference call.
> Sundar Pichai, CEO Alphabet and Google: Thank you, Jim, and good afternoon, everyone.

```
import re

# iterate through each row and select the "Speaker" and "Speech"
speaker_df_merged=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Speaker', 'Speech'])

for ind in calls.index:
    speakers = re.findall(r'\n([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+.+):', calls.iloc[ind]["Text"])
    speakers.insert(0,'Introduction')
    speech = re.split(r'\n([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+.+):', calls.iloc[ind]["Text"])

    speaker_speech_pair  = list (zip(speakers, speech))
    df_pair = pd.DataFrame(speaker_speech_pair, columns = ['Speaker', 'Speech'])
    speaker_df_merged = speaker_df_merged.append(df_pair, ignore_index = True)
    

speaker_df_merged
```

However, in the list speech of speeches, the separators are included as well. For example, `Jim Friedland, Director Investor Relations`, the separator is included in the list of speech.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] and show: an **exact, hard-coded** example of input; **exactly** what the result should be for that input; and **exactly** what the actual result is. We should be able to **copy and paste** the code in the question **without changing or adding anything**, to **directly** see the **exact** problem. Consider simplifying the surrounding code. For example, if the problem has to do with the result from the regex, do we really need to create a Dataframe in order to understand the problem?

Comment: Don't use capture groups in your regex unless you want them in your results. So use `(?: )` instead of `( )`.

Comment: I'd use e.g. [`(?P<speaker>\w[^:]*):\s*(?P<speech>[^:]+(?![^.:?!]*:))`](https://regex101.com/r/rMjdCJ/1) to separate speaker from speech, see [this Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dZBNTsNADIX3OYWbVVJCBGUXQSvEn2BDBez6g4aJk4w68QyeSavuuAbX4yJhCgWxYWdbz8@fn936xtBJ36vWGvbAGEVWeI9McBa6XJrWKo0Jx8lkeuosihXyeL6ZLYvFMC3mbrifo2zGu@FBMhnMlnkxGSyGRZrGaRR5dP7ZeQ6O8Z1q4ZoVllpQmcGlYpTeMNzSOqhC8YBaeGXIFfDUCFrB1nQ53BhTgqh2XMZQBrhG3hrCDIINbFAHTgRv4FzbRryg/3h7d1Apdv7wtRMcFmF0NDoGFEyKagfSUIWMJBGk0DqHx45KwTBVshEqg4ur@1@zryMBodb4hyqD8Mw3QP0PXh5HURWeakHRLs1KUamCKtlnnMFPNmkRAVhW5JM2r9l0tlTSJ2na958).